# What is the difference between these ways for defining functions?

Tags: kotlin

I am from a background of Javascript trying to learn some Kotlin.

I know i can define  my function by

```
fun add(a: Int , b: Int): Int{
   return a+b 
}
```

I am trying this

```
val add  = {
        a:Int,b:Int->
        println("I am calculating the sale => no body you guy [$x+$y]");
  //works

  }


val add = { a:Int ,b : Int ->
   //How do i return from this function
}
```

Also Is this a right way to define Kotlin functions? and Whats the difference with the first way ?

Comment: In JS function defined with `function` keyword are hoisted up, while others defined with `var` are not hoisted.

Comment: This is Kotlin..I know what happens in JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also Is this a right way to define Kotlin functions? and Whats the difference with the first way ?

This is not even "a way to define Kotlin functions".

In JavaScript, all functions are *reified*: they are first-class values you can refer to from variables and pass around. Not so in Kotlin, just as in many other languages like Java, C++, Objective C and so on.

A function is just a declaration, you can call it but you can't otherwise directly refer to it. Separate language features allow you to create functional objects that *delegate* to these functions, and you can pass these objects around.

Therefore,

```
fun add(a: Int , b: Int): Int {
    return a + b 
}
```

is a function declaration and

```
val add = {a: Int, b: Int -> 
    a + b 
}
```

is four things:

1. declaration of a variable `add`
2. declaration of an anonymous implementation of the functional type `(Int, Int) -> Int`
3. instantiation of this anonymous type, resulting in a functional object
4. assignment of the object to the variable `add`.

The object has a method `invoke(a: Int, b: Int): Int` whose implementation you have given in the block:

```
fun invoke(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a + b
}
```

You can call it explicitly:

```
val result = add.invoke(a, b)
```

and on top of that Kotlin defines syntax sugar that allows you to omit the explicit `.invoke`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the explicit `return` there

```
val add = { a: Int, b: Int ->
   a + b
}

add(2, 3) // => 5
```

Comment: Its actually a syntax Error to explicitly put a return

Comment: How about if i want a multiline body function with a return

Comment: and Is there any performance difference with the first way or so?

Comment: So, this is like arrow functions(denoted by `=>`) in JS. Are `a` & `b` parameters or the variables declared inside function?

Comment: They are actually parameters of the function

Comment: @henrybbosa I don't think there's any performance difference, but you should benchmark this. And regarding your other point: this simplified syntax is to facilitate writing simple expressions. Don't abuse it by shoving complex logic inside. If you need complex logic with early returns, make it a full `fun`.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: But this is a common way Used When iam doing callbacks and sometimes my callback could have some logic

Comment: @henrybbosa: nothing stops you from passing your "full" functions around. https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/c03a2b64dfb5f9a057d3ffb88384bbb5

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks alot..Some bunch of knowledge there

Comment: @henrybbosa if you want a multiline body function, just write everything without return, like [this](https://gist.github.com/aleksandar-stefanovic/25fd3bf76aed74252250521ddc6b15f3). Note that, in case of branching, you need to have all cases covered (for `if` and `when` branching you need `else` branches, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work.

```
val onChange  = {
        a:Int,b:Int->
        println("I am calculating the sale => no body you guy [$x+$y]");
  //works

  }


val add = { a:Int ,b : Int ->
    println("Sunm ${a+b}")
   //How do i return from this function
}


Log.v("Response", add(4,3))
```

**Output**
V/Response: Sum 7

Comment: My Issue is..Is How these functions internally defer and also how to return from my last function

Comment: `var add = { a:Int ,b : Int ->
            "Sum ${a+b}"
        }
        Log.v("Response", add(4,3))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't return values in kotlin like this, it will give error of type mismatch as you havn't declared any return type :

```
fun add(a: Int , b: Int){
   return a+b 
} //wrong
```

we declare return type in kotlin as :

```
fun add(a: Int , b: Int) : Int{
   return a+b 
}
```

Secondly,

```
val add = { a:Int ,b : Int ->
}
```

this is not a function, its a declaration of value assignment
In kotlin we declare function by adding "fun" before your function name as 
//you can add access modifiers(private,public,protected) if needed just before "fun"(by default its public)

```
fun add (){ //if it returns any value then add ": {datatype}" just right of "()" 
//your code here
}
```

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: About your first point..It was a typo i fixed in an edit..Second point i know I was making an assignment..Actually assigning a function to a variable. So its a function

Comment: @henrybbosa first point I didn't saw the edit, second point in that case you dont need to return, simple use a+b.